# Inner div should come outside of the parent div - Overlapping

Tags: html, css, css-float, css-position

I'm having one Parent DIV and it contains two CHILD DIV's. I need to set the first child DIV in overlapping (i.e., it should visible outside of the parent DIV, if the scroll is happened it should do as like the actual scroll)

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Div Tag Overlap</title>
<style>
div#menu {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 120%;
    background-color:deepskyblue;
    padding: 5px;
    height: 600px;
    width: 300px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    position:relative;
    z-index:1;
}
div#divSlogan {
    background-color: #FFBD01;
    width: 600px;
    height: 300px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: -1.15%;
    padding: 0.1%;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 2px #888888;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 2px #888888;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 2px #888888;
    text-align:center;
    position:relative;
    z-index:5 ;
    overflow:scroll;
}
div#text {
  width:100%;
  position:absolute;
}

div#clean {
  clear:both;
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
}
div#main {
    width:800px;
    height:800px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="main">
<div id="divSlogan">
    <div id="menu">test, test, test, test<a href="https://www.google.co.in">Link</a></div>
    <div id="clean"></div>
    <div id="text">
        Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. 
        Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. 
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Requirement:
The BLUE DIV should come outside of the Parent DIV and scroll should happen as like now. If I did the scroll, the BLUE DIV needs to go UP or DOWN

> Note: Kindly run and see the HTML in Full view mode.

Comment: can you be more specific about what you want to achieve?

Comment: @MihaiT The BULE color div need to come out side of the Parent DIV. But the functionality should be as like now. Only thing to bring the BULE color DIV outside. Scroll and all should do as like now.

Comment: you mean like using `position:fixed` ? what does ' come outside of parent` mean ?

Comment: That is not possible, you can't both have one element inside make the parent scroll and the other overflow. Let me know if a markup change is okay and I'll have a look to see how to solve something that looks the same.

Comment: If position fixed means, it won't scroll if I scrolled the parent . Am I right? I need to scroll scroll the parent, the BLUE DIV NEEDS TO SCROLL based on Parent SCROLL

Comment: And I just said, that is not possible with the existing markup

Comment: Suggest how to re-adjust the HTML?

Comment: Got busy at work, be back soon with a suggestion. When blue scroll, should the yellow stay on screen or scroll along?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

Modified `div#text` by adding `height: inherit`, `overflow: hidden`, and `top: 0`.

```css
div#menu {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 120%;
    background-color:deepskyblue;
    padding: 5px;
    height: 600px;
    width: 300px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    position:relative;
    z-index:1;
}
div#divSlogan {
    background-color: #FFBD01;
    width: 600px;
    height: 300px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: -1.15%;
    padding: 0.1%;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 2px #888888;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 2px #888888;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 2px #888888;
    text-align:center;
    position:relative;
    z-index:5 ;
    overflow:scroll;
}
div#text {
  width:inherit;
  height: inherit;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}

div#clean {
  clear:both;
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
}
div#main {
    width:800px;
    height:800px;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
<div id="divSlogan">
    <div id="menu">test, test, test, test<a href="https://www.google.co.in">Link</a></div>
    <div id="clean"></div>
    <div id="text">
        Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. 
        Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. Slogan. 
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

*(Note: open this in full page. JSFiddle's preview is too small.)*